# Typescript nest types and interfaces, for better organization

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to nest types and interfaces for better organization?

eg. `let myshark: Animals.Fish.Shark`

To allow referring the nested `Shark` interface, what kind of implementation structure of the interfaces work?

One attempt could be =>

```
interface Animals{

    interface Mamals{

        interface Bat {
            kind:string;
            wings:number;
        }
    }
    
    interface Fish {
        
        interface Shark {
            variant:string;
            color:string;
            fins:number;
        }
    }
}
```

To then use them as follows

```
let greatwhite: Animals.Fish.Shark;
let mybat: Animals.Mamals.Bat;
```

I have also tried using classes and namespaces? Is there a proper way to do this or is it not possible to get type declarations such as `let myshark: Animals.Fish.Shark`?

Comment: How is this more organized? Aren't files enough? I don't think typing a bunch of extra things helps either.

Comment: It helps to remember which types are available. eg. which animals are available in the fish category. It's better than listing every type possible when you press `.` after an imported namespace of types. eg, it would allow `let myshark: Animals.Fish.Shark`

Comment: I mean, are you looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEB2yN)? Or do `Fish` and `Mamals` also have to be interfaces?

Comment: Well yeah... but supposedly you should have a file named `fish.types.ts` or something that is descriptive enough.

Comment: you should look at namespaces instead https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#namespacing

Comment: @R4ncid do they allow reference such as `Animals.Fish.Shark`?

Comment: Maybe you could use classes and inherit them

Comment: @Jovana Will that be able to create nesting structure `Animals.Fish.Shark`? how?

Comment: You can definitely use `namespace` and then `export` the members you want accessible, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZX5ow).  If that answers your question then I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz yeah, that very much answers it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use separate [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) for each namespace, you could use TypeScript-specific [`namespace`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#handbook-content).  Either you can define them directly so that `Animals` is an actual object at runtime that can hold properties as well as types (and you need to remember to `export` anything you want visible from the outside):

```
namespace Animals {
    export namespace Mammals {
        export interface Bat {
            kind: string;
            wings: number;
        }
    }
    export namespace Fish {
        export interface Shark {
            variant: string;
            color: string;
            fins: number;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can just [`declare` the namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#ambient-namespaces) and then anything mentioned within is automatically treated as exported (since otherwise they just wouldn't be declared):

```
declare namespace Animals {
    namespace Mammals {
        interface Bat {
            kind: string;
            wings: number;
        }
    }
    namespace Fish {
        interface Shark {
            variant: string;
            color: string;
            fins: number;
        }
    }
}
```

Either way you will then be able to refer to the nested interfaces via dot notation, as desired:

```
let greatwhite: Animals.Fish.Shark; // okay
let mybat: Animals.Mammals.Bat; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBYBLMIA2UkG8BYAKCTKQgA8YB7AJwBclRJYFkBZcLXAk8gRWr0m6YAwh0AZuyQAhEEyKlBqgNZiAJgC4kUBnTEBzANz9VggO7Gou4AFcwAI0lmVqgL7myX90NqMzODQcIhIAGLoUAAWfH4CVAGi4pIyYQDK0SB0anEWggBu2egg4rr6hsCm3vlI8DTY9OUGxm615FJitsyOLnRtFr4CHgIkviQA9ABUJJoQ8NjZyCwhsmiYOHjKAitsYVxgPFs1AmIS0rIKSicWGsA6ei1VA+3WVd0Ozq43PjVD5LtQshIjE8hYzqlZJlsrltu0kEVDKUGM1KtV4hZ6o06KjWj9BJ1gB9et8Mb8-L5fFMJiQSNgIEwjHQIIpLNF0BJdOsjgA6EHRHnQnImJATCZIGhqEAATzpDKQYGlTkUXIwvIOvKuIrFEql0qAA)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is (partly) possible with `namespace`, see [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#organizing-types). Though I suspect you may not be happy with the fact you cannot nest `namespace` objects in one another without getting an error:
"*A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.(1038)*"

I personally have never done this as I don't (yet) see the benefit to it.

```js
declare namespace GreetingLib {
  interface LogOptions {
    verbose?: boolean;
  }
  interface AlertOptions {
    modal: boolean;
    title?: string;
    color?: string;
  }
}

// Usage example
const aVariable: GreetingLib.LogOptions = {};
const anotherVariable: GreetingLib.LogOptions = {
  verbose: false,
};
const someVariable: GreetingLib.LogOptions["verbose"] = false;
```

Note: you would have to initiate your variables **with some kind of value**.
TypeScript will not simply let you initiate these without providing some kind of value
(e.g. `const aVariable: GreetingLib.LogOptions = {};`)

##### In my opinion

I would much prefer the use of [extending the types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) based on some kind of mutual properties:
`"kingdom": "Plantae" | "Animalia" | ... ,`

Comment: This doesn't allow further nesting as in `let greatwhite: Animals.Fish.Shark;`